# How to use loop and test click for each tab in `http://demoqa.com/`

Tags: java, selenium

I want to use loop to change tab by click in the website

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {        

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Auto\\geckodriver-v0.11.1-win32\\geckodriver.exe");
        int i;
        WebDriver driver =new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://demoqa.com/");
        for (i=0;i<5;i++) 
            {
            WebElement a= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".//*[@id='ui-id-"+i+"'"+"]"));
            System.out.println(a);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            }

         }   

    }
```

But on doing individually its working. but, While using loop by `xpath` or `css` its not working. Also please guide me how to implement wait here without this `thread.wait`.

Comment: Looking at http://demoqa.com, it has ui-id- elements numbered 1 to 5 (eg. id="ui-id-5"), not 0 to 4 (ie. it doesn't have id="ui-id-0")

Comment: When it doesn't work... what does that mean? Please post the error message or describe what it's doing when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You started loop from 0 but ui-id-* elements on demoqa.com starts from 1 so you need to change your loop to `for (i=1;i<=5;i++)`.

thread.wait is designed to threads synchronization. For page loading use selenium waits http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp.